# How can I invite users (using devise_invitable) and populate additional fields during the invite process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

For example, when I go to `users/invitations/new`, the only field is `:email`. I'd like to invite a user and, in addition to providing their email, provide:

- first_name
- last_name
- role
- company (`user belongs_to company`)

I created `Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController`:

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
   private
   def resource_params
     params.permit(user: [:email, :invitation_token, :role, :company_id])[:user]
   end
end
```

and I added those fields to `users/invitations/new`. The invitation sends fine, but when I accept it and input a password, my validation fails saying that `No role is selected` (b/c of a validation).

How can I set these fields before sending the invite and have them persist and save when the invite is accepted? Thanks!

Comment: HI. did you find the solution for this? im running into the same problem. thanks

Comment: No, sorry. I ended up just having them set later in the process

Answer (score 2):

**Rails 5**

Here is my solution using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. If your custom attributes are directly on the user model you should be able to replace `profile_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name]` with `:first_name, :last_name, :role, :company`.

Here is my controller.

```
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  before_action :update_sanitized_params, only: :update

  # PUT /resource/invitation
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js do
        invitation_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(resource_class, :invitation_token, update_resource_params[:invitation_token])
        self.resource = resource_class.where(invitation_token: invitation_token).first
        resource.skip_password = true
        resource.update_attributes update_resource_params.except(:invitation_token)
      end
      format.html do
        super
      end
    end
  end


  protected

  def update_sanitized_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:accept_invitation, keys: [:password, :password_confirmation, :invitation_token, profile_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name]])
  end
end
```

Inside my form

```
<%= f.fields_for :profile do |p| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= p.label :first_name, class: 'sr-only' %>
      <%= p.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'First name' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= p.label :last_name, class: 'sr-only' %>
      <%= p.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Last name' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

In user.rb I have

```
...
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[:first_name].blank? }
```